# Selenium not scraping all web data

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a page in `python` using `selenium`, to get data on fantasy football data from the English premier league. I have had partial success in that I have gotten the data from the first page, however, I need to be able to click a button to get the data for the rest of the players.

To find this button I am using `selenium`, but my code cannot find the class name. I use "driver" to scrape the data from the page, and when I look into the "page source" details of this is does not show the button, but I can see the button in the html of the web page. The code below shows how I try to get the button, but it is not working. Thank you if you can help.

```
my_url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics' #this is the link
option = Options()

option.headless = True #It won't open up a tab of the website
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C://chromedriver.exe', options = option) #This goes to my chromefinder in C drive and opens the website
driver.get(my_url)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('PaginatorButton__Button-xqlaki-0 kRIEWN')
```

The html in the website I am looking for is:

```
<button type="button" class="PaginatorButton__Button-xqlaki-0 kRIEWN"
```

Comment: "but my code cannot find the class name, and when I go into the page source of my code, it does not show that this button class exists". How do you expect it to work if it is not in the source code at all.

Comment: it is in the source of the actual page. When i go into the details of "driver" which is where I scrape the page, it does not show the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PaginatorButton__Button-xqlaki-0.kRIEWN')
```

You actually have a multiple class names use css selector instead.